# React Typescript Attribute Assignable to type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, eslint, react-typescript

Having linting errors with my enum - anyone have any idea how to fix?

```
enum LinkType {
    '/suppliers/list',
    '/products/publish-list/search',
    '/offers/list',
}
export interface DashCardProps {
    data?: string;
    text?: string;
    children?: React.ReactNode | string;
    classname?: string;
    link?: LinkType | null;
}
```

```
{link ? <Link to={link}>{content}</Link> : content}
```

So this is throwing
`Type 'LinkType' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

I'm also hitting it in another spot with a different error

```
<DashCard
    key={`${v.title}-${v.number}`}
    text={v.title}
    data={v.number}
    link={v.link}
    classname="h-56"
/>
```

This one is throwing

```
Type   
'"/suppliers/list" | "/products/published-list/search" | "/offers/list"'  
is not assignable to type   
'"/suppliers/list" | "/offers/list" | "/products/publish-list/search" | undefined'.  

  Type '"/products/published-list/search"' is not assignable to type '"/suppliers/list" | "/offers/list" | "/products/publish-list/search" | undefined'. Did you mean '"/products/publish-list/search"'?
```

I can't figure out why the first is trying to assign to type never, nor why the latter is not assigning it correctly to the enum. I have tried breaking it out and just putting the strings directly in the interface as well and that hasn't worked either.

Comment: Hello Chris, did you used the same enum to annotate link property in both child and parent element?

Comment: I've tried casting it `as LinkType` in both. When I do that it tells me conversion of type 'string' to type 'LinkType' may be a mistake because neither sufficiently overlaps with the other.